# Sessions dropping on certain user types on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have something very strange going on. I just added another type of user, so I can have moderators and admin so I can have different levels of access to my site. This was working just fine with a user type 1, 2, banned, and deactive. But as soon as I added a type of 3 the sessions seem to drop.

Here is the code I have going on.

```
$loginObject = array('email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                     'password' => md5($salt.$this->input->post('password')));        
$login = $this->users_model->checkUser($loginObject);
if($login == true){
    $currentUser = $login;
    $this->session->set_userdata('currentUser', $currentUser);
    $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', true);
    $this->user = $this->session->userdata('currentUser');
    $type = $this->users_model->getUser($this->user->user_id);
    if($type[0]->type == 1){
        redirect('story/viewStories/'.$this->user->pen_name);
    }else if($type[0]->type == 2) {
        redirect('subMenu/recentStories');
    }else if($type[0]->type == 3){    
        /* This is where the sessions seem to drop */                       
        redirect('subMenu/recentStories');
     }else if($type[0]->type == 'banned'){
         $this->session->sess_destroy();
         redirect('/banned/');
     }elseif ($type[0]->type == 'deactive') {
         redirect('/home');
     }                        
}else{            
    redirect('/home/errorPage');
}
```

I have var_dumpted everything and the user values seem to be there, but as soon as it redirects to the recent stories page the sessions cease to exist. And I have logged in as each of the other users and they redirect just fine with the right sessions, it's just that user that breaks.

I have tested the type and that is there,I mean it does get to that function and redirects. I just no longer have any information on the user...and I kind of need that as that is the admin type.

Is there any reason for this? Am I just making a silly mistake?

Comment: You can check cookies and session - and compare it with other user type. You can put again `var_dump` or `echo` in different places to see what script is doing (step by step) - maybe it goes in unexpected direction. Is it the only place with `if($type[0]->type == ... )` ?

Comment: I've already done this. I can get back the user details before the redirect, but after the page is redirected the sessions disappear and never make it to the other controller....but it only happens for the one user type. I have tried re-naming the user type several times to see if that was the issus, but that seemed to make no difference and yes this is the only user type that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the constructor function in your controller class, and if it's being extended, also check the parent constructor.

dump your session variables with this quick snippet:

```
$a = $this->session->all_userdata();
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
  echo ("{$key} : {$value}<br>\n");
}
```

Also try to use a switch statement instead of so many else ifs

```
switch ($type[0]->type) {
    case 1:
        redirect('story/viewStories/'.$this->user->pen_name);
        break;
    case 2:
        redirect('subMenu/recentStories');
        break;
    case 3:
        redirect('subMenu/recentStories');
        break;
    case 'banned':
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/banned/');
        break;
    case 'deactive': // deactivate
        redirect('/home');
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is kind of interesting, when I switch to the switch and case statement if the user has a type of 3 it just returns a 0....it's not redirecting anymore.

Comment: op nope, that was a stupid mistake on my part! haha the switch statement worked like a charm! Thank you so much for the help!